# Не находит QFile в Qt

Tags: qt, c++11

Выводятся ошибки:

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\untitled3\main.cpp:7: ошибка: 'QFIle' was not declared in this scope
C:\Users\user\Documents\untitled3\main.cpp:7: ошибка: expected ';' before 'f'
C:\Users\user\Documents\untitled3\main.cpp:7: ошибка: unknown type name 'QFIle'
```

Вот файл, в котором эти ошибки(main.cpp):

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFIle>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QFIle f("file.txt");
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.setGeometry(50,50, 1200, 800);
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

untitled3.pro:

```
QT       += core gui widgets

TARGET = untitled3
TEMPLATE = app

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS



CONFIG += c++11

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 QFIle f("file.txt");
```

замените на

```
 QFile f("file.txt");
```

Comment: мда, вот невнимательность...спасибо))) жаль что нельзя удалить, ведь это нелепый вопрос...

Comment: @SonicMyst, автору ответа нужно удалить свой ответ, тогда Вы сможете удалить вопрос. Тем более, что это не ответ, а комментарий. А вопрос должен быть закрыт и удалён.

Comment: @ixSci я вами полностью согласен, в этом вопросе нет особой полезности.